# Проблема с типом данных при вычислении площади треугольника

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Здравствуйте, решаю задачку для олимпиады.

Написал код, но выдаёт что не верный результат, думаю проблема в типе данных.(Проверять размерность данных и т.п. через if и так далее - не нужно)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a,b,c, S, P,p, R;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;

    P = a + b + c;
    p = P / 2;
    S = sqrt(p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c));
    R = sqrt(((p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)) / p);

    cout << P << " "<<S<<" "<<R;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну и? Где пример входа, на котором выдается "не верный результат"? Где сам "не верный результат"?

Comment: @AnT, да всё там ясно.

Comment: @AnT,  Там не показывает какие вводные данные используют, ты просто загружаешь код и машина сверяет результат твоей программы со своими забитыми значениями.

Comment: "double numbers" - числа двойной точности, а не двойных числа. Ну и я бы вообще перевёл как "дробных".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стоит использовать формулу Герона для подсчёта площади - она приводит к переполнению или очень большой погрешности. Тебе гарантировали, что площадь не превосходит 9223372036854775807, но ты-то считаешь квадрат этого числа.

Если ничего не путаю, стоит воспользоваться теоремой синусов или косинусов.

Кроме того, надо использовать тип long double (или более точный) для всех данных и компилятор gcc (не Visual Studio). Число, указанное в качестве ограничения, это 2<sup>63</sup>-1. У обычного double есть только 53 значащих бита, чего не хватит даже для точного считывания входных данных.

Comment: Вполне может быть, что все не так экстремально, а проблема лишь в том, что умолчательный формат округляет результат всего до, скажем, 6 знаков после запятой, а по условию требуется 8. Если бы во входе наличествовали большие значения, то было бы странно формулировать требование точности в терминах *абсолютной* погрешности.

Comment: @AnT, я точно помню, что про формулу Герона говорили, что её не надо использовать из-за переполнений. Есть формулы получше.

Comment: Через радиус вписанной окружности попробую

Comment: @Пионер, а вообще, спецификатор вывода на 10 знаков действительно стоит поставить явно.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Может быть и есть и получше. Но я не вижу смысла огород городить, если дело не в этом. Еще раз: формулировка требуемой точности в терминах *абсолютной* погрешности намекает на то, что входные данные будут относительно небольшими числами.

Comment: @AnT, какие ещё намекают, если в условии прямым текстом сказано _"Входные данные гарантируют, что входы и результаты будут меньше 9223372036854775807,0"_

Comment: @Пионер, надо использовать `long double` и компилятор gcc. Потому что в `double` 9223372036854775807 = 9223372036854776000.

Comment: Для "экстремально-тупоугольного" треугольника формула Герона вообще посчитает не площадь, а нечто невразумительное...

Comment: @Qwertiy Это замечательно, но если входные данные будут приближаться к таким значениям, то обеспечить требуемую в условии абсолютную погрешность результата 1e-8 в рамках типа double будет невозможно, независимо от того, каким способом вычисления вы пользуетесь. И я почти уверен, что это задача не на использование библиотек поддержки чисел бесконечной точности.

Comment: @AnT, да что ж за число такое? Почему на Си++ получается 9223372036854775808 ([ideone](http://ideone.com/PV5iPg) и [codepad](http://codepad.org/vhQzDMqT)), на js 9223372036854776000 ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ugL4rqh/)), а на C# 9223372036854780000 ([ideone](http://ideone.com/36Lzzi))?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я отсылаю лишь код, дело не в IDE.

Comment: @Пионер, ты указываешь компилятор. VS не поддерживает long double и использует вместо него обычный 8-байтный double. Смени компилятор на gcc.

Comment: Не сработало, теже результаты.

Comment: @Пионер, тогда бери джаву и BigDecimal.

Comment: @Qwertiy, там на С++ надо.

Comment: @Пионер, а считывание тоже logn double сделал? Попробуй потестить на прямоугольном треугольнике 9223372036854775807 1 9223372036854775807. Ответ 4611686018427387903.5.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690856/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy ответ: 1.84467e+19 0 0
Все переменные long double, вдобавок везде понатыкал типизацию (long double)

Comment: @Пионер, что ещё за `e+19`? Надо выводить число точно. И что ещё за 0 0 вообще? Это же неверно. И хм.. я перестарался - не учёл ограничение на периметр. Попробуй в 2 раза меньше.

Comment: @Qwertiy Нашел проблему. Всё дело в cout. Он не правильно выводил информацию(те ешки), переделал под printf - всё заработало!