# Отображение числа 9223372036854775807

Tags: javascript, java, c#, c++, double

Почему разные языки по-разному отображают число `9223372036854775807`, хотя все используют один и тот же формат 8-байтного double для представления чисел?

`9223372036854775807` - в коде
`9223372036854775808` - C++ http://ideone.com/PV5iPg и http://codepad.org/vhQzDMqT
`9223372036854776000` - Javascript https://jsfiddle.net/5ugL4rqh/
`9223372036854776000` - Java http://ideone.com/QtXRWi
`9223372036854780000` - C# http://ideone.com/36Lzzi

Comment: По поводу C#, он всегда округляет со 15 десятичных знаков при выводе. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1658420/276994

Comment: Последовательные представимые числа в IEEE 754 `double`: `9223372036854774784`, `9223372036854775808`, `9223372036854777856`. Это объясняет `9223372036854775808` в C и C++.

Comment: @Qweriy А можете дать другое название теме своего вопроса? А то если честно думал, что связано с криптографией и стало интересно.

Comment: А разница, скорее всего, возникает только на этапе формирования десятичной записи для вывода. Внутренне все языки, я думаю, хранят и используют в вычислениях одно и то же значение `9223372036854775808`.

Comment: Правильнее сказать, не "разные языки", а "разные среды" по разному отображают длинные числа.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [IEEE-754 Double (64-bit floating point) vs. Long (64-bit Integer) Revisited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4349155/4279)

Comment: в Питоне аналогично: `'%f' % 9223372036854775807` -> `'9223372036854775808.000000'`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Comment: @alexolut, ну не дубликат же. Там про внутреннее представление чисел, а тут - про вывод.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Здесь в каждой среде/языке два преобразования:

1. Из константы в исходном коде в объект в памяти
2. Печать этого объекта памяти выбранным способом.

### C++

Эффект от кода из вопроса для
С++: [`volatile double x = 9223372036854775807.;`](http://ideone.com/PV5iPg) схож
с
[gcc's `-ffloat-store` опцией](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323#c87) и
позволяет забыть
о
[возможных дополнительных битах](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) и
думать только о 64-битных IEEE
754
[числах двойной точности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8),
используемые в рассматриваемой реализации ([IEEE 754 не
обязателен](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34295021/4279), но конкретная реализация для float чисел должна быть
задокументирована).

Константа `9223372036854775807.` из исходного кода превращается в
`9223372036854775808.` double
(ожидаемо для этого типа, см. демонстрацию битового представления внизу). В CPython тоже самое
происходит:

```py
>>> 9223372036854775807. .as_integer_ratio()
(9223372036854775808, 1)
>>> 9223372036854775807. .hex()
'0x1.0000000000000p+63'
```

то есть `9223372036854775807.` не может быть точно представлено в IEEE
754 double и поэтому используется приближение `9223372036854775808.`
(2<sup>63</sup>), которое уже выводится точно в этом случае с
помощью: [`cout << fixed << x;`](http://ideone.com/PV5iPg) как ascii-строка:
`"9223372036854775808.000000"` (в C локали).

Как double в памяти и в виде бит в IEEE 754 представлен, и как печать может происходить в С, подробно описано в ответе на вопрос [printf как средство печати переменных в С](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/628946/23044).

В данном случае, так как число является степенью двойки, то легко найти его IEEE 754 представление:

d = ±знак · (1 + мантисса / 2<sup>52</sup>) · 2<sup>порядок − 1023</sup>

- `знак`овый бит равен нулю, так как число положительное
- `порядок` = (63 + 1023)<sub>10</sub> = 10000111110<sub>2</sub>, чтобы получить 2<sup>63</sup>
- у `мантисса` все явные 52 бита нулевые (старший неявный 53ий бит всегда равен единице)

Все биты числа вместе:

```py
0 10000111110 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Что подтверждается вычислениями на Питоне:

```py
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>d', 9223372036854775808.0).hex()
43e0000000000000
>>> bin(struct.unpack('>Q', struct.pack('>d', 9223372036854775808.0))[0])[2:].zfill(64)
'0100001111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

И в обратную сторону:

```py
>>> b64 = 0b0_10000111110_0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 .to_bytes(8, 'big')
>>> b64.hex()
'43e0000000000000'
>>> "%f" % struct.unpack('>d', b64)[0]
'9223372036854775808.000000'
```

Порядок байт в памяти у числа в примере показан от старшего к
младшему (big-endian), но фактически может быть и от младшего к
старшему (little-endian):

```py
>>> struct.pack('d', 9223372036854775808.0).hex()
'000000000000e043'
```

Можно посмотреть, что не подряд идут представимые числа,
вычитая/прибавляя по одному биту к мантиссе:

```py
>>> x = 0b0_10000111110_0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

>>> def to_float_string(bits):
...     return "%f" % struct.unpack('>d', bits.to_bytes(8, 'big'))[0]

>>> for n in range(x-1, x+2):
...     print(to_float_string(n))
9223372036854774784.000000
9223372036854775808.000000
9223372036854777856.000000
```

Разница в один бит для чисел этой величины ведёт к разнице больше
тысячи в десятичном представлении: ..`4784`, ..`5808`, ..`7856`.

Можно воспользоваться [C99 функцией `nextafter()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nextafter):

```c
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  volatile double x = 9223372036854775808.0;
  printf("%f\n", nextafter(x, DBL_MIN));
  printf("%f\n", x);
  printf("%f\n", nextafter(x, DBL_MAX));
}
```

Результаты совпадают с предыдущими:

```py
9223372036854774784.000000
9223372036854775808.000000
9223372036854777856.000000
```

### Javascript

[Числа в JavaScript представлены интересным способом](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type) — целые как IEEE 754 double представлены.  К примеру, максимальное число ([`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-number.max_safe_integer)) равно 2<sup>53</sup>.

`9223372036854775807` на три порядка больше `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` поэтому нет гарантии, что `n` и `n+1` представимы.

```js
> 9223372036854776000 === 9223372036854775807
true
> 9223372036854775808 === 9223372036854775807
true
```

`9223372036854776000`
(результат [`document.write(9223372036854775807)`](https://jsfiddle.net/5ugL4rqh/) в одной из javascript  реализаций)
допустим
[cтандартом](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type) в качестве строкового представления для `9223372036854775807` (это по-прежнему одно binary64 число: `0x1.0000000000000p+63`).

Результаты побитовых операций вообще ограничены [32-битными числами со знаком](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-left-shift-operator). Можно посмотреть на какие ухищрения пришлость пойти, чтобы воспроизвести результат хэш-функции, реализованной в javascript: [Как перевести из Javascript в Питон функцию хэширования строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/592714/23044).

### Java

[В Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2), double это тип со значениями, которые включают 64-bit IEEE 754 числа с плавающей точкой.

```java
double x = 9223372036854775807.;
System.out.format("%f", x);
```

Возможная логика, почему `9223372036854776000`, а не
`9223372036854775808.` десятичное представление выбрано [для binary64
числа `0x1.0000000000000p+63`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) в том, что в общем случае это позволяет
меньше цифр печатать для дробных чисел — не отображаются завершающие
нули (это спекуляция — я не углублялся в этот вопрос).

### C#

[msdn утверждает](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx)
что double в C# соотвествует IEEE 754.

`9223372036854780000.0` намекает, что [`Console.WriteLine("{0:0.0}", x);`](http://ideone.com/36Lzzi) округляет до 15 цифр при печати.  Напечатанное число отличается от `x`:

```py
>>> 9223372036854780000. .hex()
'0x1.0000000000002p+63'
```

Вероятно это происходит по cхожей причине, что и `0.1` показывается как `0.1` при печати, а не `0.10000000000000001` или вообще `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` ( `0.1 .hex() == '0x1.999999999999ap-4'`). Более того binary64 представление другое (2<sup>63</sup> vs. 2<sup>63</sup>+2<sup>12</sup>) (единственный из представленных примеров в вопросе, который по умолчанию не выводит эквивалентное представление).

Возможно, приоритет в округлении до 15 цифр, не обращая внимание достаточно ли это, чтобы эквивалентное [binary64 представление](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) получить. Не только C# себя так ведёт, к примеру, `numpy.array` в Питоне выводит по умолчанию 8 цифр:

```py
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([2**63-1, 2**63, 2**63+2**12], dtype=numpy.float64)
>>> a
array([  9.22337204e+18,   9.22337204e+18,   9.22337204e+18])
>>> 9.22337204e+18 .hex()
'0x1.0000000176f0ap+63'
>>> numpy.set_printoptions(precision=16)
>>> a
array([  9.2233720368547758e+18,   9.2233720368547758e+18,
         9.2233720368547799e+18])
```

Показ 17 цифр в C# возможен с помощью
[стандартного](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) `"{0:R}"` формата, что [выводит
`9.2233720368547758E+18`](http://ideone.com/hNzy9h), то есть снова ту же рассматриваемую изначальную
2<sup>63</sup> степень получили:

```py
>>> 9.2233720368547758E+18 .hex()
'0x1.0000000000000p+63'
```

Comment: если вы минус этому ответу поставили, то не бойтесь оставить комментарий с указанием причины, чтобы можно было бы улучшить ответ для будущих посетителей.

Answer (score 23):

Последовательные числа, представимые в формате IEEE 754 `double`, в окрестности `9223372036854775807` это

```
9223372036854774784
9223372036854775808
9223372036854777856
```

Ближайшим является `9223372036854775808`.

А разница в выводе возникает только на этапе формирования десятичного представления двоичного плавающего IEEE 754 числа. Внутренне все вышеупомянутые реализации языков используют IEEE 754 `double`, значение которого во всех случаях равно именно `9223372036854775808`, в чем легко убедиться путем вычитания из хранимого числа его старших разрядов.

Например в вашем C# примере достаточно вместо `x` напечатать `x - 9223000000000000000`, как "недостающие" младшие разряды сразу "проявятся": http://ideone.com/H5eKPe

Абсолютно то же самое происходит и в Javascript.

Comment: В C#, `"{0:0.0}"` формат печатает отличное от введённого double число (`0x1.0000000000002p+63` в отличии от `0x1.0000000000000p+63` в других примерах в вопросе).

Answer (score 21):

Это задача с разряда, почему 0.1 + 0.1 не всегда точно 0.2. Если посмотреть в википедию, то станет понятно, что числа двойной точности имеют мантису в [52 бита](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). 52 бита дают 15-16 цифр. А у Вас их больше.

**UPD**

Нашел чудный сервис для просмотра чисел двойной точности http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html

Вбиваем в него [9223372036854775807](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=057050050051051055050048051054056053052055055053056048055) и [9223372036854775808](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=057050050051051055050048051054056053052055055053056048056), и даже [9223372036854775809](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=057050050051051055050048051054056053052055055053056048057) и видим, что у них всех одно и тоже бинарное представление - 0x43E0000000000000. Обратное преобразование для него дает [9.223372036854775808E18](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=43E0000000000000) . То есть, данный формат не может различить три заданных числа. Это отвечает на первую часть вопроса.

Почему же разные языки по разному отображают это число? Во первых, каждый из языков использует какую то свою дефолтно настроенную систему для форматирования вывода. А что именно ели/пили разработчики языка/компилятора/платформы в этот момент, мы не знаем. Во вторых, каждый разработчик пытается сделать свой, единственно верный и правильный парсер-преобразователь.

Посмотрим на вывод java и пропустим его через конвертор [9223372036854776000](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=057050050051051055050048051054056053052055055054048048048) => 0x43E0000000000000 - видим то же самое представление. Видимо алгоритм java другой. Его видимо использует и javascript (с ним правда не все очевидно - есть много различных реализаций, но все проверенные мной варианты на видне/линуксе давали один и тот же результат).

А вот у шарпа тут похоже бага: [9223372036854780000](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=057050050051051055050048051054056053052055056048048048048) => 0x43E0000000000002 (двойка в конце). Но потом они видимо исправились и ввели специальный вид форматирования - [round trip format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7#the-round-trip-r-format-specifier)

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:R}", x);
```

и в этом случае имеем 9.2233720368547758E+18, что эквивалентно 9223372036854775800. В бинарном представлении это будет все тот же 0x43E0000000000000. Заставить вывести сразу в правильной форме не получилось :(

**Вывод.** Все, кроме шарпа вывели правильно. Абсолютно правильно. Просто, по историческим (и видимо патентным/велосипедным правилам) используют разные алгоритмы предобразования. Шарп выделился, но думаю, что на то есть исторические причины (вплоть до оптимизации по скорости или просто человеческая ошибка).

Comment: 53 бита, если учесть "подразумеваемый" единичный бит. Релевантность рассуждений ваших, однако, не совсем понятна. Формат IEEE 754 может очевидным образом совершенно точно представлять огромные степени двойки, в десятичной записи которых будет намного больше 15-16 десятичных цифр. 15-16 цифр - это примерный диапазон *непрерывно* представимых целых чисел, т.е. диапазон в которым представимы все целые числа. Но в данном вопросе об этом диапазоне речи не идет вообще .

Comment: То, что формат позволяет представить некоторые числа с очень большой точностью, не значит что произвольное число можно представить с заданной точностью. Поэтому и происходит подобное.

Comment: @KoVadim, формат как бы един для всех языков, так что это не ответ.

Comment: правильно "как бы един". Но я думал над своим "ответом" и, к сожалению, в начальной версии вопроса не звучала главная проблема.

Comment: Эм.. Что именно не звучало?

Comment: я не увидел акцента на том, что это "отображение".

Comment: Хм.. Да :) http://ideone.com/sDz97X