# округление в format

Tags: python, python-3.x, print, format

```
ff = 123434534534535234234.999423423421231231
print('{:.3f}'.format(ff))
```

выдает:

```
123434534534535233536.000
```

Почему?

Comment: плавающая точка

Comment: Почему получилось `000` или как `123434534534535234234` стал `123434534534535233536`?

Answer (score 2):

123434534534535234234.999423423421231231

очень большое число для фиксированной точки и оно стало числом с плавающей точкой

1.2343453453453523e+20

считайте мы потеряли все цифры после 3523.

4234 стало 3536 из-за конвертации двоичного числа с плавающей точкой в десятичное при форматировании.

Если нужно пользоваться числами больше 12 знаков - лучше воспользоваться специальными типами из математических библиотек или из decimal.

Comment: ответ неверный. 1- ..4234 превращается в ..3536 не при форматировании, а ещё на этапе создания float объекта из константы, заданной в исходном коде. `''.format()` точно здесь печатает этот float объект.  В сторону: вне зависимости от величины `ff` это число с плавающей точкой в Питоне. Поэтому оно не "стало числом с плавающей точкой", оно всегда было числом с плавающей точкой. Даже если вы `0.1` напишите, это также число с плавающей точкой в Питоне. Подробней о плавающей точке, [смотрите ответ на вопрос, на который я выше сослался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691161/23044)

Comment: @jfs репутации у Вас  должно хватить чтоб внести уточнения в ответ)

Comment: Правки, которые смысл ответа изменяют, не приветствуются на SO.
К тому же, ответ в целом неверный, демонстрирует отсутствие понимания сути проблемы. "Уточнением" в данном случае является новый ответ. [Я этот ответ уже написал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691161/23044). Когда позволит репутация, чтобы помочь будущим читателям, можете проголосовать за закрытие данного вопроса как дубликата.