# Почему невозможно сделать побитовое смещение для вещественных чисел?

Tags: c

Даже для целых вещественных не получается, почему так?

Comment: не получается, потому что [они упакованы](http://www.puntoflotante.net/FLOATING-POINT-FORMAT-IEEE-754.htm). Распакуйте и смещайте сколько угодно. Только после этого придется еще и упаковать обратно.

Comment: Чисто формально - таковы правила языка. Почему правила таковы? Потому, что floating-point числа (даже целые) имеют намного более сложное внутреннее битовое представление в сравнении с обычными целыми, и побитовое смещение не имеет над ними особого смысла.

Comment: @mega, поясните как сделать, если можно - по-подробнее

Comment: Какой смысл вы вкладываете в такое "побитовое смещение"???

Comment: @AnT, которое записывается вот так  <<

Comment: @Elvin: Это замечательно, но именно что оно должно делать с плавающим числом? Умножение/деление на 2 - это одно. Сдвиг битов физического представления в памяти - это другое. Чего именно вы хотите?

Comment: @AnT,я просто где-то читал, что этого делать нельзя , но мне теперь стало интересно, что такое сдвиг физического представления в памяти.И да, я имел в виду деление на 2 и умножение на 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

c11 стандарт говорит (§6.5.7/2):

> Each of the operands shall have integer type.

то есть сдвиг определён только для целых типов.

Причём даже для целых, операция определена только для некоторых значений. К примеру, `i << n` не определено, если `i < 0` или `i > 0` имеет тип со знаком и результат i·2<sup>n</sup> вне диапазона типа `i` (§6.5.7/4). В переносимых случаях, *сдвиг это умножение/деление на 2*:

```
    0b01000'0001 << 1   :    129 << 1
 == 0b1000'00010        : == 258

    0b01000'0001 >> 1   :    129 >> 1
 == 0b001000'000        : == 64
```

Можно себе представить, что результат в этом случае получается буквальным сдвигом битов в двоичном представлении числа:

[image: left logical shift]

Действительные числа представлены в Си как числа с плавающей точкой. Можно думать о них как о числах, записанных в научной нотации: 1,234·10<sup>5</sup>. Более формально (§5.2.4.2.2/2):

```
           p         
          ___        
          ╲          
     e     ╲    -k   
x = b ⋅s⋅  ╱   b  ⋅fₖ
          ╱          
          ‾‾‾        
         k = 1
```

- x — само число
- s — знак (±1)
- b — основание системы счисления (к примеру, 2)
- e — показатель степени (экспонента)
- p — точность (число значащих цифр)
- f<sub>k</sub> — значащие цифры (0,1 для двоичной системы)

Пример:
x = 10<sup>6</sup>⋅(+1)⋅(1⋅10<sup>-1</sup>+2⋅10<sup>-2</sup>+3⋅10<sup>-3</sup>+4⋅10<sup>-4</sup>) = 1,234·10<sup>5</sup>

На практике представление ещё ограничено [IEEE 754 стандартом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). Чтобы освоиться, можно посмотреть на [пример миниформата числа, использующего 8 бит](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minifloat#Example): `SEEEEMMM` (1.4.3.-2). В этом формате 128.0 и 256.0 будут представлены как:

0 0101 000 = +1.000×2<sup>5-(-2)</sup> = 128.0
0 0110 000 = +1.000×2<sup>6-(-2)</sup> = 256.0

так как 101<sub>2</sub> = 5<sub>10</sub> и 110<sub>2</sub> = 6<sub>10</sub> (смещение экспоненты `-2`).

[Не хватает точности, чтобы 129.0 и 258.0 представить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690856/23044), поэтому используются ближайшие представимые числа: 128.0 и 256.0. Умножение на два — это просто увеличение экспоненты на один для нормальных чисел.

Сдвиг непосредственно битового представления числа особого смысла здесь не имеет:

129.0 << 1 = 0 0101 000 << 1 = 0 1010 000 = +1.000×2<sup>10-(-2)</sup> = 4096.0
258.0 >> 1 = 0 0110 000 >> 1 = 0 0011 000 = +1.000×2<sup>3-(-2)</sup> = 32.0

Даже для положительных целых чисел (все явные биты мантиссы нулевые), представленных в таком формате, сдвиг отличается от умножения/деления на 2. Ещё пример:

0 1000 001 = +1.125×2<sup>8-(-2)</sup> = 1152.0
0 1000 001 >> 1 = 0 0100 000 = +1.000×2<sup>4-(-2)</sup> = 64.0
0 1000 001 << 1 = 1 0000 010 = -0.250×2<sup>1-(-2)</sup> = -2.0

Здесь буквальный сдвиг битов представления меняет и знак и дробную часть. Вводить такую операцию не слишком полезно.

Вот [конвертор из битового представления во float](https://ideone.com/byAvHO) и [обратно](https://ideone.com/VPoB64).

Comment: по поводу `сдвиг это умножение/деление на 2` сами понимаете что к отрицательным сдвиг часто применяют... Там не совсем деление на 2 (округление не в ту сторону)

Comment: @pavel: прочтите всё предложение: «**В переносимых случаях**  сдвиг это умножение/деление на 2». Для отрицательных чисел либо вообще не определён сдвиг (`<<`) либо зависит от реализации (`>>`).

Comment: я понимаю. но остальная часть верна почти для любого ЯП. Может в канонический ответ даже...

Comment: @pavel: другие языки это отдельная тема (даже для c++ слова отличаются). К примеру, для javascript `1.0 >> 1` работает (double как 32-bit целое).

Comment: @pavel кстати, в Питоне сдвиг именно как умножение/деление на 2 определён. Значения для отрицательных чисел можно интерпретировать как дополнительное представление с бесконечным числом 1 слева ([подробней тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/835511/23044))

Answer (score 2):

Бинарное представление таких чисел отличается от бинарного представления целочисленных, поэтому здесь и результаты побитовых операций отличаются.

Любое вещественное число представлено в виде

```
1.m * 2^e
```

где `m` - мантисса, `e` - экспонента.

Вот из этих `e` и `m` и состоит бинарное представление числа, только значение `e` еще сдвинуто на полдиапазона, чтобы автоматически учитывался знак экспоненты при арифметических операциях над ними.

Побитовый сдвиг вещественного (как и целочисленного) - это умножение или деление на 2, поэтому побитовый сдвиг вещественного равнозначен приращению экспоненты, например, сдвиг влево:

```
1.m * 2^e * 2^1 = 1.m * 2^(e+1)
```

Подробности можно узнать из стандарта [IEE754](http://www.softelectro.ru/ieee754.html)

Comment: снова, зачем минус ставить? Ответ показывает упрощённую, но аккуратную картину. Из двух приходящих на ум интерпретаций "побитового смещения" `f<<=1`: **1-** умножение на 2: `f *= 2` (вариант, используемый в javascript (double->32-bit ints)) **2-** буквальное смещение битов: f=SE..EM..M -> f=E..EM..M0 — второе просто не имеет смысла (здесь S - бит знака, E..E биты [смещённой] степени, M..M биты, представляющие числа после запятой).

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Это называется "деление на два" и "умножение на два".

Comment: зачем минус ставить? ldexp() как раз умножением на степень двойки занимается.