# Побитовое исключающее или (XOR) в C++ для double

Tags: c++, операторы

У меня в коде есть такая строка `temp3(k,j)^=temp3(i,j);`,  `temp3` это матрица типа `double`. При компиляции выводится такая ошибка:

> ***.cpp:128:22: error: invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator^’
>                   temp3(k,j)^=temp3(i,j);
>                             ^
>       mymain.cpp:128:22: error:   in evaluation of ‘operator^=(double, double)’

Помогите исправить ошибку.

**UPDATE**
вот вся функция:

```
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (temp3(i,i)==0)
                for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
                {
                    if (temp3(j,i)==1)
                    {
                        for (int k=0; k<2*n; k++)
                        {
                            int c=temp3(j,k);
                            temp3(j,k)=temp3(i,k);
                            temp3(i,k)=c;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            for (int k=i+1; k<n; k++)
            {
                if (temp3(k,i)==1)
                {
                    for (int j=0; j<2*n; j++)
                    {
                        temp3(k,j)^=temp3(i,j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                for (int k=i-1; k>=0; k--)
                {
                    if (temp3(k,i)==1)
                    {
                        for (int j=0; j<2*n; j++)
                        temp3(k,j)^=temp3(i,j);
                    }
                }
            }

return (temp3);
}
```

Comment: А что должна возвращать операция исключающего или с двумя `double` - ну, например, что такое `3.14^2.72`?

Comment: @Harry, если честно точного назначения не знаю. я взял функцию которая возвращает обратную матрицу и вставил в свой код.

Comment: Без ясного ТЗ получается ХЗ... ответ на ваш вопрос дать не получится, потому что вы и сами не знаете, что хотите. И что-то меня терзают смутные сомнения (с), что таким образом можно получить обратную матрицу...

Comment: связанный вопрос [Почему невозможно сделать побитовое смещение для вещественных чисел?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/745290/23044)

Comment: Покажите больше кода чего там творится.

Comment: словами опишите что вы хотите получить. Не используйте сломанный код в качестве спецификации задачи. Также приведите пример ввода и желаемого вывода. Не помещайте в вопрос весь код, который у вас есть, вместо этого создайте [mcve]

Comment: @jfs это только часть кода, где находится обратная матрица

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я вангую что там

```
x ^= y; y ^= x; x ^= y;
```

Используйте `std::swap(x, y);`.