# Побитовый сдвиг числа Double C++

Tags: c++, vector

Приветствую! 
Я начинающий программист, поэтому, если вопрос "детский" - не стоит врубать быка.
Есть лабораторка, в которой нужно выполнить XOR шифрование массива вещественных чисел (double), с оговоркой, что перед этим нужно выполнить побитовый сдвиг вправо каждого числа.
Как обойти то, что с double переменными не применяются битовые операции сдвига?
Или мне нужно выполнять сдвиг после приведения в char?

С шифрованием, вроде, разобрался:

```
std::vector<double> arrDouble = { 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };
char key = 'r';
int size = sizeof(arrDouble);
for (int i = 0; i < arrDouble.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << "My array: " << arrDouble[i] << " ";
}
std::cout << "\n\nCripted arr: ";

for (int i = 0; i < arrDouble.size(); i++)
{
    unsigned char* item = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&arrDouble[i]);

    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(double); j++)
    {
        *(item + j) ^= key;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < arrDouble.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << arrDouble[i] << " ";
}
std::cout << "\n\n";

system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: ну допустим, побитовый сдвиг вправо есть быстрый способ целочисленного деления на два (или другое число, равное 2 в степени сдвига).

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Почему невозможно сделать побитовое смещение для вещественных чисел?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/745290/23044)

Answer (score 1):

1. `sizeof(arrDouble)` вернет 24, а не 3 как ожидается в цикле `for`
2. Битовый сдвиг. Ты прав, надо сначала кастить к unsigned типу, потом делать сдвиг. Только не понятен один момент. После побитового сдвига ты навсегда потеряешь младший бит, как потом будешь декодировать число назад?

Comment: Может, в условии забыто слово "циклический"? :) Циклический сдвиг вправо... И, кстати, при сдвиге вправо теряются младшие биты.

Comment: Да. Прошу прощения. Я упустил, что сдвиг должен быть циклическим

Comment: По поводу sizeof(). Я там написал не arrDouble, а просто double.
Ожидается, что sizeof(double) вернет кол-во бит, исп. в типе double.
Если я не ошибаюсь, конечно.