# Что означает символ ">>"?

Tags: python

Что означает символ `>>`?

Видел в примере:

```
x = 5
print(x >> 2)
```

Ответ: 1

Comment: Битовый сдвиг .

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы узнать, что какой-то оператор делает в Питоне, можно вызвать `help('>>')` функцию в Python REPL или `pydoc "<<"` с командной строки. Пример: [Что делает оператор "^" в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/477581/23044)

Полученный вывод говорит, что `>>` это сдвиг в Питоне и подробности доступны как [`help('SHIFTING')`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations):

> A right shift by *n* bits is defined as division by "pow(2, n)".

То есть, в Питоне, **правый сдвиг определён как деление на соответствующую степень двойки**. Дополнительно, в CPython `n` ограничено `sys.maxsize`.

```py
>>> 22 >> 2
5
>>> 22 // 2**2
5
>>> -22 >> 2
-6
>>> -22 // 2**2
-6
```

Для неотрицательных чисел достаточно в двоичном представлении отбросить `n` бит, чтобы сдвинуть вправо `x >> n`:

```py
>>> bin(0b10110 >> 2)
'0b101'
```

Об отрицательных числах можно думать как будто они представлены в [дополнительном коде (бесконечное число единиц слева)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5), но так как бесконечное количество единиц нельзя показать, то Питон показывает `-bin(abs(x))` и трюк с отбрасыванием битов при таком отображении уже не работает так как `abs(x)` для `x < 0` равно `-x = ~x + 1`:

```py
>>> bin(-0b10110 >> 2)  # ...11101010 >> 2
'-0b110'                # ...11111010 = -(0b101+1) = -0b110
```

Answer (score 3):

Оператор `x >> n` возвращает число, которое получается из `x` сдвигом всех бит на n позиций вправо, при этом самые правые `n` бит отбрасываются. Например:

```
x = 43      # 0b101011
a = x >> 1  # 0b10101 == 21
b = x >> 2  # 0b1010 == 10
c = x >> 3  # 0b101 == 5
d = x >> 5  # 0b1 == 1
```

Comment: для отрицательных чисел уже нельзя просто отбросить биты в представлении, возвращаемом `bin()`. См. [пример в моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835613/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Математически эту операцию (`x >> N`) можно представить как целочисленное деление на 2^N (с отбрасыванием остатка):

```
 5 >> 2 -> 5 / (2^2) = 1
 130 >> 3 -> 130 / (2^3) = 16
```

Противоположная операция (сдвиг влево) - умножение на 2^N:

```
3 << 3 -> 3 * (2^3) = 24 (0b00000011 -> 0b00011000)
```