# mt_rand выходит за заданный диапазон

Tags: php

Собственно вызываю `$CardCookie = mt_rand(6103006430040008016, 6103006430040020000);` , на выходе при генерации некоторых карт вылезает за указанный диапазон, замечено что на 24 значения где-то.

Как лечить?

Comment: У меня большие подозрения, что даже для 64битной системы у вас превышение максимального значения для integer тут присутствует.

Comment: Как быть? Мне надо карты сгенерить в этих диапазонах

Comment: `Диапазон min - max не должен выходить за границы mt_getrandmax(). То есть (max - min) <= mt_getrandmax(). В противном случае, mt_rand() может возвращать менее качественные случайные числа.`

Comment: Префикс выделите из числа `1030064300` и генерируйте только оставшуюся часть от 40008016 до 40020000. В ответ возвращайте строку, а не число, полученную конкатенацией строки `1030064300` и результата генерации.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну, разность max и min там как раз небольшая

Answer (score 0):

[mt_getrandmax();](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mt-getrandmax.php) - покажет, не превышен ли порог максимально возможного рандомного числа возвращаемого mt_rand. Если да, [mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mt-rand.php) может давать погрешность.

```
mt_rand(min, max);  (max - min) <= mt_getrandmax()
```

Comment: Реализовал через такое решение:    $randCanc = 61030064300;
      $randGen = mt_rand(40008016,40020000);
      $CardCookie = $randCanc . $randGen;

Answer (score 0):

Число слишком большое и не представимо точно в типе double.

Можно заметить, что на Си++ выводится другое значение: https://ideone.com/2pJ4uh

```
printf("%.0f", 6103006430040020000.);
```

```
6103006430040019968
```

Связанный вопрос: [Отображение числа 9223372036854775807](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690856/178988)