# Непонятное округление числа в Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть у меня в базе в колонке значение, например, 8722879621216817228, но при вытягивании обычным запросом из базы, последние три цифры превращаются в ноль -> 872287962121681700. Но и не только с базой эта проблема у меня возникает, она везде присутствует.

```
let a = 8722879621216817228;
console.log(a); //8722879621216817000
```

Как быть с данной проблемой, может кто-то ссылку на документацию знает, то буду благодарен, так как я ничего не нашёл по данной ситуации.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ хотя бы на какой-то раздел сошлитесь, плиз. Всю страницу читать незачем.

Comment: Получайте своё значение из БД как строку, а не как число.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я тоже думал как строку вытягивать, но надеялся есть вариант решения с числом.

Comment: @ivani если у вас сервер, тоесть nodejs >= 10.4.0, то попробуйте bigint

Comment: @StrangerintheQ та я взял проще, использовал в запросе функцию cast и преобразовал в char, чтобы потом сравнивать не как числа, а как строку

Comment: если Вам только сравнивать то да, BigInt для арифметики

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690856/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-9223372036854775807), на который сослался модератор, закрывший этот вопрос как дубликат, хоть и содержит 3 ответа, однако несет мало информации о решении этой проблемы в разрезе `javascript`.**

---

**В javascript** `Number`, без потери точности, может быть не больше **2<sup>53</sup>-1** [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) или меньше **1-2<sup>53</sup>** 
 [`Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_SAFE_INTEGER)

Есть метод для проверки попадания числа в указанный диапазон:

[`Number.isSafeInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger)

```js
console.log(Number.isSafeInteger(8722879621216817))
console.log(Number.isSafeInteger(872287962121681722800))
```

---

Сравнительно недавно появился **[BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)**

**BigInt**  - позволяет использовать большие числа с высокой точностью

> Чтобы создать `BigInt`, добавьте суффикс `n` в любой целочисленный
>   литерал. Например, `123` становится `123n`. Глобальную функцию `BigInt`
>   можно использовать для преобразования обычного числа в `BigInt`. Другими
>   словами, `BigInt (123) === 12`3n.

Чтобы получить `BigInt` со значением больше **2<sup>53</sup>** в конструктор `BigInt()` можно передать строку содержащую число в десятичном формате.

```js
    let n1 =                    "123456789123456789";
    let n2 = "1234567891234567890000000000000000000"
    console.log(BigInt(n1).toString());
    console.log(BigInt(n2).toString())
    console.log((BigInt(n1)+BigInt(n2)).toString())
```

Поддержка, на 7 марта 2019, судя по MDN такая:

```
10.4.0 node.js
67     Chromium
65     Firefox
54     Opera
--     Edge
--     IE
--     Safari
--     Firefox Android
```

---

Для **длинной** арифметики, не зависящей от окружения можно использовать решения на  **чистом** javascript, вотнекоторые из них:

[bignuber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/)

[decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/)

[big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/)

Comment: Не является решением проблемы, хотя и объясняет её источник.

Comment: @Akina, решения нет :-) только использовать библиотеки для длинной арифметики и хранить такие числа как строки

Comment: @Grundy *решения нет* отож... *использовать библиотеки для длинной арифметики **и** хранить такие числа как строки* вероятно, "или"? а то ить длинные числа можно хранить/обрабатывать и как массив не очень длинных.

Comment: @Akina, ну это можно в пункт _использовать библиотеки для длинной арифметики_ - они ж именно так и хранят у себя :-) под и/или, непонятно получилось, я имел ввиду для вывода и передачи куда-нибудь дальше

Comment: @Grundy добавил про big int, может быть Вам будет интересно

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, пока это только предложение, соответственно и поддержка хромает.

Comment: @Grundy для nodejs вполне, темболее что у автора похоже именно сервер